# computer is in password lock mode/ in black bios screen? 12.04 64 bit

Tags: 12.04, password

My new download from 10.04 to 12.04 upgrade has been a disaster for me so far. i cannot understand why my desktop screen password/authenticate whichever will not reconize my password , but after every 3rd time it opens up anyway. I went ot this site and found some options so I went to try my 1st option and now im stuck completly . I just pressed ctl+ alt+ T

And then it went to lock mode, an all black screen. That repetetly asks for my password, but does not allow keyboard input.

It lets me try 2 times then says it is shutting down.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link that may help it will allow you to reset your password. [password reset](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/resetpassword)